# How To Fix or Clean Corrupted JSON Files

Tags: python, json, twitter

I have a corrupted JSON file for a public tweet as such:

```
"{\"created_at\":\"Thu Feb 25 05:05:41 +0000 2021\",\"id\":1364803731678715907,\"id_str\":\"1364803731678715907\",\"text\":\"\\u201cMe solta crlh\\u201d\",\"source\":\"\\u003ca href=\\\"http:\\/\\/twitter.com\\/download\\/iphone\\\" rel=\\\"nofollow\\\"\\u003eTwitter for iPhone\\u003c\\/a\\u003e\",\"truncated\":false,\"in_reply_to_status_id\":null,\"in_reply_to_status_id_str\":null,\"in_reply_to_user_id\":null,\"in_reply_to_user_id_str\":null,\"in_reply_to_screen_name\":null,\"user\":{\"id\":870120437132529664,\"id_str\":\"870120437132529664\",\"name\":\"vraulentina\",\"screen_name\":\"florescabrall\",\"location\":\"Dourados, Brasil\",\"url\":null,\"description\":\"hmm, sei la\",\"translator_type\":\"none\",\"protected\":false,\"verified\":false,\"followers_count\":336,\"friends_count\":339,\"listed_count\":0,\"favourites_count\":32475,\"statuses_count\":16889,\"created_at\":\"Thu Jun 01 03:30:53 +0000 2017\",\"utc_offset\":null,\"time_zone\":null,\"geo_enabled\":true,\"lang\":null,\"contributors_enabled\":false,\"is_translator\":false,\"profile_background_color\":\"000000\",\"profile_background_image_url\":\"http:\\/\\/abs.twimg.com\\/images\\/themes\\/theme1\\/bg.png\",\"profile_background_image_url_https\":\"https:\\/\\/abs.twimg.com\\/images\\/themes\\/theme1\\/bg.png\",\"profile_background_tile\":false,\"profile_link_color\":\"1B95E0\",\"profile_sidebar_border_color\":\"000000\",\"profile_sidebar_fill_color\":\"000000\",\"profile_text_color\":\"000000\",\"profile_use_background_image\":false,\"profile_image_url\":\"http:\\/\\/pbs.twimg.com\\/profile_images\\/1364803281785085954\\/ITyuznjA_normal.jpg\",\"profile_image_url_https\":\"https:\\/\\/pbs.twimg.com\\/profile_images\\/1364803281785085954\\/ITyuznjA_normal.jpg\",\"profile_banner_url\":\"https:\\/\\/pbs.twimg.com\\/profile_banners\\/870120437132529664\\/1554819329\",\"default_profile\":false,\"default_profile_image\":false,\"following\":null,\"follow_request_sent\":null,\"notifications\":null},\"geo\":null,\"coordinates\":null,\"place\":{\"id\":\"9ae7de89f4e0fcc0\",\"url\":\"https:\\/\\/api.twitter.com\\/1.1\\/geo\\/id\\/9ae7de89f4e0fcc0.json\",\"place_type\":\"city\",\"name\":\"Dourados\",\"full_name\":\"Dourados, Brasil\",\"country_code\":\"BR\",\"country\":\"Brasil\",\"bounding_box\":{\"type\":\"Polygon\",\"coordinates\":[[[-55.521651,-22.441805],[-55.521651,-21.880052],[-54.201264,-21.880052],[-54.201264,-22.441805]]]},\"attributes\":{}},\"contributors\":null,\"is_quote_status\":false,\"quote_count\":0,\"reply_count\":0,\"retweet_count\":0,\"favorite_count\":0,\"entities\":{\"hashtags\":[],\"urls\":[],\"user_mentions\":[],\"symbols\":[]},\"favorited\":false,\"retweeted\":false,\"filter_level\":\"low\",\"lang\":\"pt\",\"timestamp_ms\":\"1614229541116\"}\r\n"
```

Ultimately I just want the text and the coordinates provided. I am using StreamListener in my code to collect the tweets as JSON files and send them to a file location on my computer. The JSON files collect in real time but when I open them they look like this and are not readable or able to be used to map. Can someone please provide some insight on code to either collect tweets in real time in a readable format or how to fix the JSON files I am getting? Thank you.

Comment: There's nothing corrupt about that JSON entry. Pasting that string into `json.loads()` works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

If what you mean is that you've accidentally saved a `repr()` of the JSON into a file, you can un-`repr()` it with `ast.literal_eval()`:

```
import ast
import json

file = ...
json_string = ast.literal_eval(file.read())
json_data = json.loads(json_string)
assert isinstance(json_data, dict)
```

Comment: I am not sure I know what you mean, how can they be cleaner when simply collected without this extra step?

Comment: I don't know how you've collected the data, but if what you pasted into your question is what is in your file, you've written `repr(some_json_string)` into the file, and decoding it to a dict takes first un-repring the data.

Comment: My code is written using StreamListener and is being sent to a folder on my computer. Do you know if added this  repr(some_json_string) into the code will decode the files as you stated?